# how to structure availability relationships

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am building a recruitment database and need to structure 'current availability' data against candidates which can be one of three options - available now, a specific date (e.g. 5/3/2019) or a relative date (e.g. 4 weeks). When querying the database in my application the relative date will be calculated on the fly.

I am trying to work out the best way to store this data in a relational database. In my project I am using MySQL 5.7. I have tested and can see that storing this as JSON is possible e.g. the availability field in candidates table can be JSON with the following

```
{
    'immediate': true
}
```

or

```
{
    'relative': {
        'period': '4',
        'unit': 'Weeks'
    }
}
```

or

```
{
    'date': '2019-03-05'
}
```

the query can be something like this

```
select `candidates`.*, 
CASE
    WHEN availability->>'$.immediate' = 'true' THEN date(now())
    WHEN availability->>'$.date' THEN date(availability->>'$.date')
    WHEN availability->>'$.relative.unit' = 'week' THEN date(DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL availability->>'$.relative.period' WEEK))
    WHEN availability->>'$.relative.unit' = 'month' THEN date(DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL availability->>'$.relative.period' MONTH))
END as available from `candidates`
order by `available` desc
```

Although this works I am adverse to using JSON in a relational database so wondering how the same result could be achieved in other more relational ways.

Comment: Do you really want to shift the availability by one day tomorrow?  And another day on the next day?

Answer (score 1):

IMO you overcomplicate things. Just add an `available DATE` field to the `candidate` table. Then queries will be simpler and more performant.

```
SELECT * FROM candidate WHERE available < NOW() ORDER BY available DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback but I don't think you have understood my problem.

Comment: @the-a-train - It is better to do the arithmetic _before_ storing the data.  And then don't hide it in JSON, rather have a simple `DATE` column.

Comment: But then I don't know whether the candidates availability is now (unemployed looking for a job), relative (needs to give 4 weeks notice at current job) or a specific date (currently in a contract that ends on a particular date).